# Why is the .NET SDK not found after installation on Ubuntu 22.04?

Tags: .net, linux, ubuntu, dotnet-sdk

I'm trying to install the .NET SDK on my Ubuntu 22.04 system, but I'm running into some issues. After following the installation steps, I can't seem to find the SDK anywhere on my system. Here's what I've done so far:

1. I removed any existing .NET packages with the following command:

```bash
sudo apt remove 'dotnet*' 'aspnet*' 'netstandard*'
```

This seemed to remove the existing .NET SDK 7.0 and other related packages.

2. I then checked if the SDK was removed:

```bash
ls /usr/lib/dotnet/dotnet
ls /usr/lib/dotnet/
```

Both commands confirmed that the SDK was not present.

3. Finally, I tried to reinstall the SDK:

```bash
sudo apt-get update && \
sudo apt-get install -y dotnet-sdk-7.0
```

The installation seemed to go smoothly, but when I checked again, the SDK was still not found.

`dotnet --list-sdks` shows nothing, `dotnet --help` works and shows the help menu. `dotnet --version` gives this message:

```bash
dotnet --version
The command could not be loaded, possibly because:
  * You intended to execute a .NET application:
      The application '--version' does not exist.
  * You intended to execute a .NET SDK command:
      No .NET SDKs were found.

Download a .NET SDK:
https://aka.ms/dotnet/download

Learn about SDK resolution:
https://aka.ms/dotnet/sdk-not-found
```

list runtimes worked:

```bash
dotnet --list-runtimes
Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 7.0.11 [/usr/lib/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
Microsoft.NETCore.App 7.0.11 [/usr/lib/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]
```

And the directories were rebuilt:

```bash
ls /usr/lib/dotnet/
dotnet  host  LICENSE.txt  packs  shared  ThirdPartyNotices.txt

ls /usr/lib/dotnet/dotnet
/usr/lib/dotnet/dotnet

ls /usr/lib/dotnet/shared
Microsoft.AspNetCore.App  Microsoft.NETCore.App
```

I'm not sure what I'm missing here. Why is the SDK not showing up after installation? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is my release:

```bash
lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Pop
Description:    Pop!_OS 22.04 LTS
Release:    22.04
Codename:   jammy
```

Answer (score 2):

To find the SDK I ran

```bash
find / -name dotnet
```

Then I looked into the directories shown in the response. I found the SDK in `/usr/share/dotnet`.

```bash
ls /usr/share/dotnet
sdk  sdk-manifests  templates

ls /usr/share/dotnet/sdk
7.0.401
```

Next, I found the dotnet executable with:

```bash
which dotnet
/usr/bin/dotnet
```

`/usr/bin/dotnet` ended up being a symbolic link to `/lib/dotnet/dotnet`.

Since dotnet executable was in a different location than the SDK, I made a new symbolic link of the SDK diriectory and placed it in the `/lib/dotnet` directory

```bash
sudo ln -s /usr/share/dotnet/sdk /lib/dotnet/sdk
```

Now `dotnet --list-sdks` works correctly:

```bash
dotnet --list-sdks
7.0.401 [/usr/lib/dotnet/sdk]
```

Finally, I was able to use `dotnet run` to start my application.